# Is createUserWithPhone possible? Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

First question here sorry if it obvious, i'm a beginner.

I'm trying to change the auth of my app from email and pass to phone number with verification.

The problem i'm facing is that Firebase doesn't have a `createUserWithPhone` like it has `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, so after the verification is done it automatically creates a user in the database with a pre-selected category.

As i have two types of users in the app i need to separate them in the database.

so, is it possible to `createUserWithPhone`?

I was successful in implementing the login with the phone and the user gets to the homepage. What i'm not being able to do is what i was doing with this:

```
Future<void> registerWithEmailPassword({
@required String email,
@required String password,
@required String name,
@required int idade,

}) async {
try {
  FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password))
      .user;

  final userTypeOne = UserTypeOne(
      idade: idade,
      email: user.email,
      nome: name,
      id: user.uid);

  await _customerService.verificyExistsByEmailAndSave(userTypeOne);

  userInfoEvent.add(userTypeOne);
  _customerService.setStorage(userTypeOne);
} on PlatformException catch (ex) {
  throw ex;
} catch (ex) {
  throw ex;
}


}
```

If anyone could help would be awesome,
Thank you.

Comment: That's known as Phone Number authentication. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth, which on Flutter translates to `verifyPhoneNumber`: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/verifyPhoneNumber.html

Comment: Im gonna edit the question, i should explain it better. I already implemented the login with phone verification, it works and i can get the user to the homepage. But i want to separate them in two categories as i was doing  with createUserWithEmailAndPassword.